# Ant <property> task: is there a difference between 'value' and 'location'?

Tags: java, ant

When setting a `property` to refer to a filepath, is there a difference between using the `value` or `location` parameters?

The documentation at https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/property.html states that:

`value` sets the value of the property

`location` sets the property to the absolute filename of the given file.

So is `value` for general values, and `location` just for filepaths?

---

In a real life example, is there a difference between these two lines of code? If so, what actual impact does it have?

```
    <property name="cobertura.dir" value="C:/Cobertura/cobertura-1.9" />
    <property name="cobertura.dir" location="C:/Cobertura/cobertura-1.9" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is documented in the ANT manual you have already referred...

```
location : Sets the property to the absolute filename of the given file. 
If the value of this attribute is an absolute path, it is left unchanged (with / and \ characters converted to the current platforms conventions). 
Otherwise it is taken as a path relative to the project's basedir and expanded.
```

So you have the option of specifying an absolute/ relative path.

So location is used if you want to do relative paths. Either location or value (mutually exclusive) can be used if you're doing absolute paths

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I don't think that answers my question yet, as your quotation from the manual is referring to (the value of) `location` alone. It doesn't explain the difference between the `location` and `value` parameters.

Comment: Edited my answer for a better picture. Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps anyone else:

At http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=135, the writer recommends:

> For properties that represent a file or directory, use the 'location'
>   attribute, not 'value'
>
> .properties files equate to using `<property name='x' value='y'>`
>   since the 'location' attribute isn't used. This isn't recommended for
>   files and directories, since this will not resolve relative
>   references. If you do specify a location in a properties file, then it
>   should be absolute, not relative. In addition, you'll need to escape
>   backslashes.